# How can I make a dynamic SQL Server query with sliding dates but specific times?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, maximo

I'm trying to make a dynamic query which searches records from 9 days ago at 21:00 to 2 days ago at 23:00.

I've been asked to make a weekly report in Maximo which lists all records between Sundays at 21:00 and the following Fridays at 23:00. The report must generate each week on Tuesdays at 6:00. I have pieced something together from other queries but can't figure out where to go from here:

```
startdatetime >= dateadd(hour, 21, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
and startdatetime <= dateadd(hour, 23, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

I've used `DATEADD` before to show all records between certain times of the current day. What I can't figure out is how to get those times for previous dates. I tried doing "...dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()-9),0) and ...dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()-2),0)", but I got a SQL error code 207. I obviously don't understand how the second DATEADD segment works. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close, you just need to change the second zero to the days you want to move.

```
WHERE startdatetime >= dateadd(hour,21,dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),-9))
AND startdatetime <= dateadd(hour,23,dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),-3))
```

The error 207 refers to an invalid column name. Make sure that you don't have any typos on your query and that the columns actually exist.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea what that last '0' was for; I thought these dateadd/datediff functions required actual dates, not 0s. This answers my question!

Comment: The 0 is representing the date '1900-01-01'. Datetime values use an integer to store the date internally, so each day can be represented by an integer. -3 is actually '1899-12-29' and so on. You could, of course, change the integer values into dates to make more evident what you're doing, but once you understand it, it's simpler to use integers.

Answer (score 0):

Using `0` as a base (which equates to `1900-01-01`) is not very intuitive or self-documenting. Also writing a query that assumes it will only ever run on a Tuesday is a bit dangerous; we can make it so that if it needs to be run again on Wednesday or Thursday it still yields the right results.

```
-- first, let's make sure we know what weekday is a Sunday
DECLARE @OriginalDateFirst int = @@DATEFIRST;

IF @OriginalDateFirst <> 7
BEGIN
  SET DATEFIRST 7;
END

-- let's figure out today
DECLARE @today datetime = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()),
        @weekday int = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE());

-- if weekday is 3 (Tuesday), the previous Sunday is today -2, 
-- and the Sunday before that is today -9

-- if weekday is 4 (Wednesday), the days are -3, -10
-- if weekday is 5 (Thursday),  the days are -4, -11
-- and so on

-- so the range is -6-@weekday to 1-@weekday
DECLARE @MostRecentSunday datetime = DATEADD(HOUR, 23, DATEADD(DAY,  1-@weekday, @today)),
        @PreviousSunday   datetime = DATEADD(HOUR, 21, DATEADD(DAY, -6-@weekday, @today));

-- make sure this is what you want:
SELECT @PreviousSunday, @MostRecentSunday;

-- now your query just says:
... WHERE startdatetime >= @PreviousSunday
      AND startdatetime <= @MostRecentSunday;

-- let's put the datefirst setting back
IF @OriginalDateFirst <> 7
BEGIN
  SET DATEFIRST @OriginalDateFirst;
END
```

Yes, it's definitely more code (though you can condense it quite a bit if you like, and if you know nobody messes with `DATEFIRST`, you can clear out some of that logic, too).

But I'm a big fan of making code self-documenting vs. terse/cryptic.

Comment: You're right; having the report run only on Tuesdays at 6 a.m. isn't ideal, but the way our Maximo is set up, we don't have full administrator privileges. We aren't able to set 'datefirsts' unless we do it through the company who runs the program. But honestly, I didn't know we could even do that, so thanks!